# Submit multiple queries same time mysql inserting same id twice

Tags: php, mysql

Want to submit auto-increment value of `table_a` into `table_b` at same time. I first inserting record  into `table_a` and then fetching last primary `id` from `table_a` and inserting it into `table_b`.
It works well at slow speed like 20 records per sec, but a fast speed and multi user level it inserting duplicate id of `table_a` into `table_b`.

[image]

Is my approach is wrong ? Please suggest better way to do this.

code

```
query1 = "insert into `table_a` (`aid`,`name`) values(null,'val')";

query2 = "select `id` from `table_a` order by `id` desc limit 1";

$aid='retrieved_value';

query3 = "insert into table_b (`bid`,`aid`,`btype`) values (null,'$aid','val')";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your approach is wrong. It is very racy. You have no guarantee that `query2` returns the id related to `query1`. A better approach is to use the [last_insert_id](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html) function.